# El arreglo de entrada de tu tabla es demasiado largo, Datatable y C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Mi problema es que tengo un datatable de 48 posiciones que seria el siguiente:

```
    #region tablaRectificacionesImportaciones


        dt_rectificacionesImportaciones.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[48] 
          { 
            new DataColumn("idPedimento", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fecha", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fechaVencimiento",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idCveDocEntrada",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idTipoCambio",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("seguros",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fletes",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("embalajes",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("otros",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("valorComercial",typeof(string)),//10
            new DataColumn("valorAduana",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("observacion",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("dta",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("prevalidacion",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("factura",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("cove",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fechaFactura",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idProveedor",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("icoterm",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idMoneda",typeof(string)),//10
            new DataColumn("factorMoneda",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("numParte",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idTipoBien",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("secuencia",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idFraccion",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idPaisVendedor",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idPaisOrigen",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idUnidadComercial",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("cantidad",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("precioUnitario",typeof(string)),//10
            new DataColumn("valorAduanaPartida",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idTasa",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("preferencia",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idForPago",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idForPagoIVA",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("IVA",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("pedimentoRectificado",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("descargado",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fechaIngreso",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fechaActualizacion",typeof(string)),//10
            new DataColumn("idUsuario",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("ipActualizacion",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("falta",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("cantidadUMT",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("iva_f",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("fechaRemesa",typeof(string)),//6
            new DataColumn("valorAduana_f",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("idEmpresa",typeof(string)) 

          });

        #endregion
```

Tambien en una parte de mi codigo relleno eso tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
            //Se recorre la lista lstTablaRectificadoImpo para llenar la tabla dt_rectificacionesImportaciones
            foreach (TablaRectificacion tblRetificaImpo in lstTablaRectificadoImpo)
            {
                dt_rectificacionesImportaciones.Rows.Add(tblRetificaImpo.IdPedimentoOriginal, tblRetificaImpo.Fecha, "", tblRetificaImpo.IdCveDoc, tblRetificaImpo.IdTipoCambio,
                            tblRetificaImpo.Seguros, tblRetificaImpo.Fletes, tblRetificaImpo.Embalajes, tblRetificaImpo.Otros, tblRetificaImpo.ValorComercialME,
                            tblRetificaImpo.ValorAduana, tblRetificaImpo.Observacion, tblRetificaImpo.Dta, tblRetificaImpo.Prevalidacion, tblRetificaImpo.Factura,
                            tblRetificaImpo.Cove, tblRetificaImpo.FechaFactura, tblRetificaImpo.IdProveedor, tblRetificaImpo.Icoterm, tblRetificaImpo.IdMoneda,
                            tblRetificaImpo.FactorMoneda, tblRetificaImpo.NumParte, tblRetificaImpo.IdTipoBien, tblRetificaImpo.Secuencia, tblRetificaImpo.IdFraccion,
                            tblRetificaImpo.IdPaisVendedor, tblRetificaImpo.IdPaisOrigen, tblRetificaImpo.IdUnidadComercial, tblRetificaImpo.Cantidad, tblRetificaImpo.PrecioUnitario,
                            "", tblRetificaImpo.IdTasa, tblRetificaImpo.Preferencia, tblRetificaImpo.IdForPago, tblRetificaImpo.IdForPagoIVA,
                            tblRetificaImpo.IvaFrac, originalRectificado, "", tblRetificaImpo.FechaIngreso, tblRetificaImpo.FechaActualizacion,
                            tblRetificaImpo.IdUsuario, tblRetificaImpo.IpActualizacion, "", "", tblRetificaImpo.IvaFrac,
                            "", tblRetificaImpo.ValorAduana_f,idEmp);
            }
```

Por lo que tengo entendido este error se debe a que estoy tratando de meter mas datos de los que inicialmente defini en mi tabla, pero creo que ese no es el problema real, ya que si define los espacios correctos, de hecho el problema surgio al agregar este valor a la tabla:

```
empresa
```

Si yo quito ese valor en mi for each sale lo siguiente al hacer un debug.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me crea la tabla con mi columna pero le pone por defecto un cero y si le agrego el valor que deberia ir en esa posicion me sale el siguiente error:

> Input array is longer than the columns in this table

No se a que se deba si mi columna existe pero al agregar un valor a dicha columna ya no quiere funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el codigo que pusiste de la tabla y el foreach son exactamente 48 posiciones para 48 posiciones, si agregas en el foreach `empresa` el foreach tendria 49 posiciones para 48 posiciones de la tabla lo cual se excede y genera el error:

> Input array is longer than the columns in this table

En el caso de:

> Si me crea la tabla con mi columna pero le pone por defecto un cero y
>   si le agrego el valor que deberia ir en esa posicion me sale el
>   siguiente error

el 0 proviene de tu foreach donde pones `idEmp` el cual es la posicion 48 de tu tabla y el foreach usa esa variable para rellenar la poscion 48, y por lo que comentas:

> Por lo que tengo entendido este error se debe a que estoy tratando de
>   meter mas datos de los que inicialmente defini en mi tabla, pero creo
>   que ese no es el problema real, ya que si define los espacios
>   correctos, de hecho el problema surgio al agregar este valor a la
>   tabla:
>
> empresa

El valor `empresa` parece ser el valor que quieres agregar en la posicion 48 o de lo contrario tendrias que agregar un campo mas a la tabla:

```
new DataColumn("idEmpresa",typeof(string), //<-- posicion 48
new DataColumn("Empresa",typeof(string) //<-- Posicion 49
```

y tu foreach:

```
tblRetificaImpo.ValorAduana_f, //posicion 47
idEmp, //posicion 48
empresa //posicion 49
```